# Cmake ExternalProject_Add not retrieving entire project

Tags: cmake

I'm currently using Cmake to add in a static library into my project. Below is my current set up that partially works. By partially I mean that in order for the file to be properly downloaded, I must build the project, then clean it, then build it two successive times for the project to be valid. Is there anything inherently wrong with what I'm doing below that would lead to the project being only partially downloaded?

```
ExternalProject_Add(
REI_LIB
SVN_REPOSITORY "repo I'm using"
PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/rei_lib
CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=<INSTALL_DIR>
)

ExternalProject_Get_Property(REI_LIB install_dir)
include_directories(${install_dir}/include)
```

Here is the Cmake file of the the repo and retrieving the project from:

```
    #Set a minimum Version
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} /MTd")


#Name the project
project("REI_LIB_STANDALONE")

#Create List of Headers and Source files
set(SOURCES)
set(HEADERS)

#Add in the source from this dir
set(SOURCES ${SOURCES} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp)

#Add in the source and headers from all the required sub directories
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/IO)
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/MATH)
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/MESH)
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/SYSTEM)
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/UTILS)
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/XML)

#Add in the include dir
include_directories(${INCLUDE_DIRS})

#Add each file SOURCE to the correct source dir
foreach(sourceFile ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})
    #Exact the dir
    set(dir)
    get_filename_component(dir ${sourceFile} DIRECTORY)

    #Get the relative path between the main and this file
    file(RELATIVE_PATH dir ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}  ${dir}) 

    #Convert the dir to a cmake dir only if dir is not empty from / to \\
    if(NOT ${dir} STREQUAL "")
        STRING(REGEX REPLACE "/" "\\\\" dir ${dir} )
        #file(TO_NATIVE_PATH ${dir} dir)
    endif()

    #Set file in source group
    SOURCE_GROUP(${dir} FILES ${sourceFile})
endforeach(sourceFile)


set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-DBOUNDSCHECK  ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG}")

add_executable(REI_LIB_STANDALONE ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})
add_library(REI STATIC ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})

install(TARGETS REI DESTINATION lib)
install(FILES ${HEADERS} DESTINATION include)
```

Comment: It might be that the build scripts for the retrieved project are to blame here. `ExternalProject_Add` is quite difficult to misuse and from what little you wrote, it should work just fine.

Comment: I've updated it with the other file, is there anything on their that might lead to this happening?